# PHP Getting Key from object where key is integer

Tags: php, object

I have an object in PHP

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[974]
   public '@attributes' => 
     array (size=1)
     'index' => string 'vDEF' (length=4)
   public 0 => string 'Link Title' (length=10)
```

How can i return the value public 0 ?

I have tried

```
 $obj[0]
 $obj->0
 $obj->[0]
```

None of which give me the result..

Using PHP 5.7

Updated code to give an Array

```
array (size=2)
   '@attributes' => 
   array (size=1)
      'index' => string 'vDEF' (length=4)
      0 => string 'Link Title' (length=10)
```

Comment: First, convert your object into Array for better understanding and post Array in your question using this. $array =  (array) $yourObject;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe

`$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($object);
 $property = $reflection->getProperty(0);`

or

`$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($object);
 $property = $reflection->getProperty('0');`

Answer (score 0):

That debug output is generated by Laravel's `dd` helper method, from the following XML:

```
<root index="vDEF">Link Title</root>
```

You don't need to use Reflection or iterate over object properties to access **Link Title**. It's simply the text content of your SimpleXMLElement object, and you can access it by just casting the object to a string:

```
echo (string) $object;
```

Using Reflection in particular is a very slow process, and should be avoided wherever possible.

SimpleXML provides a full API to access attributes and elements of an XML document, but when you start examining it with `var_dump`/`dd`/`etc`, it's not always obvious. Read [the basic documentation for the library](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), and there'll be an easy option.